# Using geom_text in a for loop with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I want to display a list of text labels on a ggplot graph with the geom_text() function.

The positions of those labels are stored in a list.

When using the code below, only the second label appears.

```
x <- seq(0, 10, by = 0.1)
y <- sin(x)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
g <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()

pos.x <- list(5, 6)
pos.y <- list(0, 0.5)

for (i in 1:2) {
  g <- g + geom_text(aes(x = pos.x[[i]], y = pos.y[[i]], label = paste("Test", i)))
}

print(g)
```

Any idea what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how `geom_text` can be used within a for-loop, but you can achieve the desired result by defining the text labels in advance and using `annotate` instead. See the code below.

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(0, 10, by = 0.1)
y <- sin(x)
df <- data.frame(x, y)

pos.x <- c(5, 6)
pos.y <- c(0, 0.5)
titles <- paste("Test",1:2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + 
annotate("text", x = pos.x, y = pos.y, label = titles)
```

Answer (score 8):

I agree with @user2728808 answer as a good solution, but here is what was wrong with your code.

Removing the `aes` from your `geom_text` will solve the problem. `aes` should be used for mapping variables from the `data` argument to aesthetics. Using it any differently, either by using `$` or supplying single values can give unexpected results.

#### Code

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  g <- g + geom_text(x = pos.x[[i]], y = pos.y[[i]], label = paste("Test", i))
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice answer, as it deals specifically with the loop aspect of the question.